# How to calculate log-normal parameters using the mean and std of the given distribution

Tags: probability, lognormal-distribution

I have the mean (u) and the standard deviation (sd) of a continuous distribution (X). How do I solve for the mean (u_log) and standard deviation (sd_log) of the log of that continuous distribution (log(X))?

I am looking to draw random numbers from a log-normal distribution. The problem is, most statistical packages have a log-normal-random-number-generator function that takes the mean of log(X) and sd of log(X) as inputs.

I only have the mean of X and std of X.

How to I solve for mean(log(X)) and sd(log(X)) given those inputs.

Comment: see below for answer:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

In contrast, the mean, standard deviation, and variance of the non-logarithmized sample values are respectively denoted m, s.d., and v in this article. The two sets of parameters can be related as (see also #Arithmetic moments below):[3]

Comment: This reads like routine bookwork. Is this for some subject?

Answer (score 15):

Let m and s be the mean and sd of $X$ on the original scale.  The appropriate mean and sd on the log scale can be found after a little algebra to be

$E(\log(X)) = \log(m) - \frac{1}{2} \log [ (s/m)^2 +1]$

$sd(\log(X)) = \sqrt{\log [(s/m)^2 +1]}$